# Django 404 Error: path doesn't go down urls.py

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

So I'm trying to make an index.html for the homepage of my Django project. I made an app called pages.
[image]

Note that the templates folder is empty (moving index.html to templates did nothing). admin.py and models.py also contain nothing.

I configured my TEMPLATES settings as such:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

In my root project folder, urls.py looks like this.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include
# from pages.views import home_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('homepage/', include('pages.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('explorer/', include('explorer.urls')),
]
```

In the views.py file of the pages app:

```
from typing import ContextManager
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    # Render the HTML template index.html
    return render(request, 'index.html', context=ContextManager)
```

In the pages app (not project root folder), urls.py looks like this (I created this file myself):

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

And index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Test</title>
<p>Test</p>
```

Here is the full file structure.

[image]

Here is what happens when I run the server:

[image]

Where http://127.0.0.1:8000/ is the root directory of the localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your root urls doesn't have anything for `''`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('homepage/', include('pages.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('explorer/', include('explorer.urls')),
]
```

I'm guessing you want `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` to go to the index that's why you wrote this:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

But with this config, the index will be on `http://127.0.0.1:8000/homepage/`. If you want it to be set to `/`, change the root url config to:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('explorer/', include('explorer.urls')),
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
]
```

And lastly, you need to put the html back to `templates` as django only looks for templates on those folders.

Answer (score 0):

The index.html should be inside templates folder.
pages/templates/index.html

Comment: nah man same thing. i even tried migrating it after i moved it but it said nothing to migrate.